# How to use javascript object destructuring on a subset of an argument and maintain reference to all remaining properties in single value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use typescript/javascript object destructuring to target only a subset of the objects properties while maintaining the remaining properties of the object in its own variable, "catching all other properties/keys".

My use case is related to using inheritance to extending a class while attempting to leave the api's the similar. In the example below I only want to use object destruction for properties `onlyForB` and `alsoOnlyForB` while pass all remaining properties to `config` variable.

```js
class A {
   constructor(config) {
     this.name = config.name;
     // ...
   }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor({ onlyForB, alsoOnlyForB, ..config }) { // using ...config doesn't work
    this.onlyForB = onlyForB;
    this.alsoOnlyForB = alsoOnlyForB;
    super(config);
  }
}


const b = new B({ onlyForB: "B", alsoOnlyForB: "B2", name: "Satoshi", age: 100});
/**
 Trying to achieve the following in class B's constructor

   onlyForB -> "B"
   alsoOnlyForB -> "B2"
   config -> { name: "Satoshi", age: 100 }

*/
```

When I try this with `{ onlyForB, alsoOnlyForB, ..config }` which is similar to creating objects with the spread syntax I get errors. In the real use case I am extending an open source class that has mainly "config" properties and using typescript.

Is there a way to achieve this without manually deleting all the object's properties specific to the `B` class?

*Side Note: For those familiar with python I am trying to achieve something similar to what `**kwargs` does, ie. `def __init__(self, onlyForB, alsoOnlyForB, **kwargs)`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of possible ways to do something like this; here is one example:

```js
type ConfigForB = {
    onlyForB: string,
    alsoOnlyForB: string,
    age: number,
    name: string
}

type ConfigForA = Omit<ConfigForB, 'onlyForB' | 'alsoOnlyForB'>

class A {
   private name: string 
   constructor(config: ConfigForA) {
     this.name = config.name;
     // ...
   }
}

class B extends A {
  private onlyForB: string
  private alsoOnlyForB: string
  constructor({ onlyForB, alsoOnlyForB, ...config }: ConfigForB) {
    super(config);
    this.onlyForB = onlyForB;
    this.alsoOnlyForB = alsoOnlyForB;
  }
}

const b = new B({ onlyForB: "B", alsoOnlyForB: "B2", name: "Satoshi", age: 100});
```

I've defined a `ConfigForB` type that has the four properties listed in your example, and used that type in the constructor for `B`. Then I've used the [`Omit<Type, Keys>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to construct a new `ConfigForA` type, which is exactly the same as `ConfigForB`, except it's without the `onlyForB` and `alsoOnlyForB` keys.

If I were to define this explicitly, it would look like this:

```js
type ConfigForA = {
    age: number,
    name: string
}
```

This would also work, by the way - using `Omit` is just nice since you don't have to repeat yourself.

You can try this out on TS Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=82&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAxOAnAQlAXigG8AoKCqRAGxCzwC4oBnYbFBNAGnMoENqzOAHkEteriat2nHpSh80EJggCuAWwBGEbHMoI+65SzYc0pAL6lSoSLESpMOAIKEow9SmAAeeMnQSXFAA5DR0OLjBUAA+IQJCouIRwQB81gDG1HzMzFCuZJRg7ABufMDQBkZSppxQvFDpiNKq6cA4ABSN-mhMfo70zgCUJPUUwAAWKMwAdJXQRF2Os4YQANyjUAD0m1DTe-VWVqSZ2bn4EAAe5QgAJrn5vEUopeVUYuGMJjLmFE8v0PERO8JNVvrwus1Wh1iG8knggoDEh9cEE9tNFugoBZeg4AhFhgVKMxVJBsJ1cWhBut5BMptMwhI3AyItTKLSZojgRE3Jy4bhWYcMk1gFBNG4EBAAO5QXDtGHMz4AIlwioRgiBfKYyoATKqoHMtQBlMpwZiTPWKYwARgADDaLFSgA).